# Python - using Popen object twice

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I have no problem creating the Popen object and running another program with it by making it use cmd where output is the arguments i'm sending...

```
k = subprocess.Popen(output, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

but then I want to use the same Popen object to run another command through the same command prompt. Ive used communicate() and it didnt work, also stdout. I'm now using stdin.write() in conjunction with stdout.readline().

```
f = open("sample.txt")    
reed = f.read()
f.close()
k.stdin.write(reed)
p="i"
while p.find("0.0)") == -1:
    p = p+k.stdout.readline()
print p
```

what should I do?

**EDIT**

```
p = k.communicate(input=reed)[0]
```

that was the only thing I needed. I didn't know I had to use 'input' in communicate, I was always just using communicate(reed). I don't even need that silly old while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using subprocess.call instead?

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. It does not improve my situation. What is happening is the first command is executed when its first created and the resulting text is read correctly into p and printed correctly. The problem is when (code above) a second file is opened and stored into a variable then when i try to use that text as an argument to the same command prompt nothing happens. It seems that I cannot call the same command prompt a second time.